# I want to add moment to fingers on Vincent model in blender

Tags: mesh, rigging, bones, pose-mode

I've been playing with this Vincent model which I have downloaded from blender cloud.
Everything seems to be good
but while playing with the fingers part, I'm not able to bend the bones correctly

[image: screenshot of Vincent hand]

I want to clench the fist but in the pose mode
after selecting that finger and clicking on  "R"
I tried to change position but this is how it is:

[image: hand after motion showing bad positioning]

Is this the way? If not, then what exactly is the way to move fingers? I've tried move and rotate commands. Is there any other process for this?

[attached blender file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/o8j70kf1snsmwh7/__d8c0fb4e88474929b68e663466239576.blend?dl=0)

please have a look.

Answer (score 2):

There is a common technique used in modeling hands: use the *scale* of a control bone to set the curvature of the finger.  If you want to move the finger naturally, in pose mode, select the red rectangle that's right above it and use <kbd>S</kbd> to scale it.  scaling up uncurls the finger. scaling down curls it.

[image: finger curled by scaling the control bone]

Vincent uses a rig called [BlenRig](https://cloud.blender.org/p/blenrig/) and you can find out more about the controls of that rig on the Blender Cloud site.

Answer (score 0):

just select this in pose mode:

[image]

and move it and you will get this:

[image]

Comment: well to be fair the OP wrote *"i want to clench the fist "*

Comment: Thanks Blunder. I am happy that you can read. This cannot everybody here….‍♂️